# I want to join a software shop, but I'm not a good programmer yet

Tags: new-job

I want to join a regular software shop. But I am not good enough programmer to be called an expert. Should I study more programming and get more experience first? Or should I just go for try to apply for a job and see what future holds for me.

Comment: Why you wanna join if you think you are not too good?

Comment: If we all waited until we were experts before trying to get our first job, none of us would have started a career

Comment: I'm no expert. That comes with learning on the job I have

Comment: Do interview preparation - there are countless sites dedicated to giving sample interview problems and mock interviews, in general and for specific companies. That will tell you whether you're good enough to pass programming interviews (although interviews vary a lot between companies), and it will also help you pass the interview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Submit your CV, do whatever coding test you are given. If you are able to pass the tests, take the job. If not, study more about programming.

Comment: That pretty much wraps that up!

Answer (score 1):

How about a code-related job that is not "front line" coding, such as writing and performing unit tests, regression testing etc, or business analysis?

You get to do paid work, rub shoulders with devs and hopefully pick up some skills from them too.

Answer (score 0):

Look for companies that offer a traineeship or internal academy; you'll be paid and trained at the same time. It's a good way to earn experience while also getting some actual work experience.